# PlayFramework and Angular: How to load public files (css, js, img) only once?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, playframework, assets

I'm working with Play! Framework and AngularJS and I'm having problems. My AngularJS Services doesn't save the values that I change between pages. I change a value on a page, and the next page when I see the value is null. I realized that Play! loads the files statically.

How do I upload the files only once, so keep my js variables in their states throughout the application? It is related to the assets?

Comment: Depends where you set your variables and what requirements you have to save data, you show no code at all, so what you write is quite ambiguous

Comment: This is not related to how Play loads public assets, but instead how you are using angular. If your angular code requires a page reload, then all variables will be lost. You are probably looking for how to create [Single Page Applications](http://singlepageappbook.com/index.html).